# What is the benefit of installing plutus playground locally?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

In these instructions for working through the plutus pioneer program, it suggests installing the playground locally:
https://tutorials.cardanoacademy.io/plutus-pioneer-program/setting-up-plutus-playground/starting-plutus-playground

However, the end result is to then just use the same web gui but on your localhost instead of running it on:
https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/

So, are those docs just outdated or is there some advantage to running it locally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The Plutus playground deployed on playground.plutus.iohkdev.io is often out of date and might contain bugs that are already fixed in upstream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however, the latest can sometimes also have fresh bugs.  I would think that the online playground would be a more stable version.  Additionally, from a functionality standpoint are you saying there is no difference?  If there is no functional difference then there would be no functional benefit.